# How to import data with query function along with OR Condition in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, import, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet where i am trying to import data from another sheet using query function and applying condition "does not contain" and "OR" function.

Here is a google sheet link
[Google sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19NCGzrWJTC21VrkdGFvqUPVQoYYeZhV8Z8dmzQxfX-8/edit?usp=sharing)

"1st data" is 1st sheet . i am trying to import "1st data" content based on certain condition into second sheet "2nd data" .

Condition is if 1st data "column H" Post data "does not contain" "2d" or "3d" or "4d" or "1w" or "1mo" then remaining data show on 2nd data sheet.

desired result will be  1d or 1h or 2h etc. in post date column and their desired rows will be displayed

i used following formula but failed to get desired result

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19NCGzrWJTC21VrkdGFvqUPVQoYYeZhV8Z8dmzQxfX-8/edit?usp=sharing","1st data!A1:K200"),"where not Col8 contains '1d'|'1mo'")
```

any other formula or script based solution is welcomed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra `'` either side of the `|`.

Instead, try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19NCGzrWJTC21VrkdGFvqUPVQoYYeZhV8Z8dmzQxfX-8/edit?usp=sharing","1st data!A1:K200"),"where not Col8 matches '.*d.*|.*h.*|.*m.*'")
```

or

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19NCGzrWJTC21VrkdGFvqUPVQoYYeZhV8Z8dmzQxfX-8/edit?usp=sharing","1st data!A1:K200"),"where not Col8 like '%d' and not Col8 like '%h' and not Col8 like '%mo'")
```

`%` is a wildcard when using `like`.

Comment: i used your formula but it is not working in my scenario

Comment: it is showing all data , "does not contain" with OR is not working, all data is displaying with out condition fulfilling